# Can't arrange 3 displays with 2 on top and one below

Tags: display, thunderbolt, hdmi

I have a 2013 MacBook pro with Catalina (10.15.7) and have added 2 external displays, one on hdmi, one with a thunderbolt VGA adapter. All 3 (the builtin LCD and 2 external) are used and not mirrored.

When I try to arrange the two external displays side by side above the LCD in the displays settings "arrangement" tab, it refuses to move the third one (whichever I arrange last).

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I leave the displays settings (ie: go to the settings home window) and then back to "displays", I'm able to arrange the monitors as I desire (!?).

Comment: If that's an answer and resolves the issue, why do you use a question mark at the end?

Comment: I guess I'm surprised about it.. I also see it as a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: I don't think Answers are restricted to "solutions;" they also include work-arounds and other less-than-complete solutions to the problem.